# Access website on android tablet from computer

Tags: android, webserver, tablet, bit

I have a web server setup on my android tablet using Bit Web Server and I was to access the website from my desktop because because it is easier to make some of the changes on a desktop. Is it possible to access a locally hosted site on an android from a desktop? If it is possible how?

Comment: Do you mean you `want` to access the site?

Comment: Exactly, I want to use my computer to view the site that is hosted on my tablet.

Comment: You'd have to have access to the source file. Maybe a program that exposes it to the network would work. I don't know of any though.